# Which first book should i start with in Hinduism?

Tags: book-recommendation

I am a new reader to this. I want to start with a book. Which book should i start with ?

Answer (score 0):

You could read a low level introductory book that nevertheless gives a decent overview of Hinduism. Otherwise you will have difficulty in understanding Hindu scriptures. Books like 'The Hindu mind' by Bansi Pandit and 'The complete Idiot's guide to Hinduism' by Linda Johnsen would help. Another introductory text is 'A primer of Hinduism' by D. S. Sharma. A good text is 'Essentials of Hinduism' by Swami Bhaskarananda. A good survey of Hindu scriptures is 'Windows into the Infinite A guide to the Hindu scriptures' by Barbara Powell. An advanced level beginner text is 'The Spiritual Heritage of India' by Swami Prabhavananda. You can also read 'Hindu Gods and Goddesses' by Swami Harshananda to learn about the many Hindu Gods and Goddesses.

Comment: I would also add beginning with "Hindu Culture" by Swami Tejomayananda, then with "All about Hinduism" by Sri Swami Sivananda (available for free to read on archive.org), and then "The Vedas" by Sri Chandrasekharendra Saraswati.